How do I display a carousel of YouTube videos in this Angular 16 movies app?
I have been working on an SPA with Angular 16, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).
I run into a problem while working on displaying a movie trailers in a Bootstrap 5 carousel.
In app\services\movie-service.service.ts I have:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../models/Movie'; 
import { Trailer, TrailerResponse } from '../models/Trailer';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MovieService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getMovieTrailers(id: Number): Observable<TrailerResponse>{
    return this.http.get<TrailerResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/${id}/videos?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }

  public getMovieDetails(id: Number): Observable<Movie>{
    return this.http.get<Movie>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/${id}?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }
}

In app\models\Trailer.ts I have:
export interface Trailer {
    id?: string;
    key?: string;
    name?: string;
    site?: string;
}

export interface TrailerResponse {
    results?: Trailer[];
}   

I have created a TrailerCarouselComponent component with the folowing ts file:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Trailer } from '../../models/Trailer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-trailer-carousel',
  templateUrl: './trailer-carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trailer-carousel.component.scss']
})
export class TrailerCarouselComponent {
  @Input() trailers!: Trailer[];
}

And this template:
<div id="trailersCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false">
  <ol *ngIf="trailers.length > 1" class="carousel-indicators">
    <li
      *ngFor="let video of trailers; let i = index"
      data-bs-target="#trailersCarousel"
      attr.data-slide-to="{{ i }}"
      class="{{ i === 0 ? 'active' : '' }}"
    >
      {{ i + 1 }}
    </li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div
      *ngFor="let video of trailers; let i = index"
      
      class="carousel-item"
      [ngClass]="{ 'active': i === 0 }"
    >
      <iframe
        class="embed-responsive-item"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video.key }}"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I use the above component in the MovieDetailsComponent component:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from '../../models/Movie';
import { Trailer, TrailerResponse } from '../../models/Trailer';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-details',
  templateUrl: './movie-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-details.component.scss']
})

export class MovieDetailsComponent {

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  public movie!: Movie;
  public trailerResponse!: TrailerResponse;
  public trailers: Trailer[] | undefined = [];


  public getMovieTrailers() {
    const movie_id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    this.movieService.getMovieTrailers(movie_id).subscribe((response) => {
      this.trailerResponse = response;
      this.trailers = this.trailerResponse.results;
      
      if (this.trailers && this.trailers?.length) {
        this.trailers = this.trailers.slice(0, 5);
      } 
    });
  }

  public getMovieDetails() {
    const movie_id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    this.movieService.getMovieDetails(movie_id).subscribe((response) => {
      this.movie = response;

      // get movie trailers
      this.getMovieTrailers();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovieDetails();
  }
}

Template:
<div *ngIf="trailers && trailers.length" class="mb-3">
  <h2 class="section-title">Trailers</h2>
  <app-trailer-carousel [trailers]="trailers"></app-trailer-carousel>
</div>

There are no compilation errors and yet, there is a surprising (for me) problem.
The problem
Insted of the desired result, I get this error in the browser:
NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context
...
 at TrailerCarouselComponent_div_3_Template (trailer-carousel.component.html:22:9)
 

The line in question is src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video.key }} from:
<iframe
    class="embed-responsive-item"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video.key }}"
  ></iframe>

This is all the more surprising for me since I have already made this app with Vue3 and Typescript and did not encounter the problem.
UPDATE
Using a pipe, as suggested by @Kosta did not wokr for me. I have added a Stackblitz.
Questions

What am I doing wrong?
What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?


First issue is you are passing not sanitizied url to iframe, which by default isn't allowed in angular. Create a pipe that will bypass the security of the iframe URL.
ng g p bypass-sanitize

import { Pipe, PipeTransform, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'bypassSanitize',
  standalone: true,
})
export class BypassSanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private readonly domSanitizer = inject(DomSanitizer);

  //  constructor(private domSanitizier: DomSanitizer) {} old way but still working

  transform(value: string) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
}


Since your component doesn't have the standalone property, I assume your app is based on modules. You can import this pipe inside NgModule.
After you add it to NgModules, let's use this pipe:
<iframe
    class="embed-responsive-item"
    [src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video.key | bypassSanitize"

Warning: calling this method with untrusted user data exposes your application to XSS security risks!
Answer for second question is to use pipes instead of functions which will be directly used inside of html, this will trigger many time change detection, better approach is pipes or handling source via observables(stream).
For example:
  readonly frameUrl$ = this.SomeStreamForYourFrameUrl$.pipe(
    map((url) => this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)),
  );

<iframe
    class="embed-responsive-item"
    src="{{frameUrl$ | async }}"
  ></iframe>

This is more better approach keep in mind async is pipe for listening streams, by this way you don't have to use subscribe on stream.
Try to use more often signals or observables (rxjs)

I get ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[BypassSanitizePipe -> BypassSanitizePipe]. I have added a stackblitz.

Update: I added the BypassSanitizePipe in thew providers array, in app.module.ts. And I still have the error: Error: NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context. Have a look at the stackblitz.

Issue was i suggested incorrect way to pass oneway binding it was much more like 'hack', but it's great for rxjs usage. just update src passing line:
[src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video.key | bypassSanitize" and it should work. Here is stackblitz, keep in mind stackblitz will not display iframe for security reasons. Btw when u are importing pipe it should go in declrations array not in providers and it's not necessary to inject in constructor

Please try answering this question too. Thanks!

There can be unsafe URLs, when it's dynamically generated, so we need to ensure a sanitized trusted URL goes into src, we can use bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl from DomSanitizer of Angular to ensure the URL is sanitized.
html
<iframe
    class="embed-responsive-item"
    [src]="trustUrl(video.key)"
  ></iframe>

ts
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
...

...
trustUrl(key: string): string {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${key}`) as string;
}
...


I get the error Cannot find name 'SecurityContext'. Did you mean 'isSecureContext'? in app\components\trailer-carousel\trailer-carousel.component.ts

@RazvanZamfir we need to import SecurityContext, could you try this? it is located in @angular/core

I did that, and the iframe contains the entire page. The  source is<iframe _ngcontent-ng-c2152715611="" src="trustUrl(video.key)" class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>. Maybe <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="trustUrl(video.key)"></iframe> is wrong?

@RazvanZamfir sorry about that, we need to add the property binding [src] updated my answer!

I did that too, and I get an TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' error.

@RazvanZamfir updated! added type

What fixes the compilation error is <iframe *ngIf="video.key" class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="trustUrl(video.key)"></iframe>, but... no video is displayed.

@RazvanZamfir try bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl instead, updated the answer stackblitz demo

I have updated the question with details about the parent component. Please gave a look
